# embedding a groovy client in Java not working

Tags: groovy

I would like to have a groovy console (command line) running within a Java process. I've defined the simple code as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Groovysh shell = new Groovysh();
    shell.run();
}
```

When I run this under Windows 7, using 'groovy-all' Maven dependency I get the Groovy prompt, but pressing Enter seems to not clear the buffer and there's no way to move before "groovy:000>".

I understand that perhaps JLine is not working here. How do I pass the "--terminal=none" to the main(), if this is the correct work around?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments on the call to run().

```
String[] args = { "--terminal=none" };
shell.run(args);
```